# Machine Learning: creating a prediction without previous trends

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a machine learning algorithm that allows one to give an input a classification without a grouping or previous classification? Example: with a dataset of 5 digit numbers, the user inputs a random 5 digit number (12345), can the machine output "alteration" when 12345 is similar to something in the dataset, or output "completely new" when 12345 or anything similar doesn't exist? To clarify, the machine would do something like "alteration" when it finds something similar to 12345 such as 12445 where its only number difference, and output "completely new" when no similar numbers exist.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight I don't see the need for ML, you just need a similarity measure which would return a score between two objects:

1. Given the input object, say "12345", compare it against any known object using the similarity measure. The result is a similarity score for every known object.
2. Rank the known objects according to their similarity against the input object, or just obtain the object with the highest similarity. for example "12445" is the most similar with score 0.8.
3. Apply a threshold $t$: if the max similarity is higher than $t$, then the corresponding known object is returned; otherwise the system says that the input object is "completely new".

Of course ML could still be used, for instance to tune the similarity measure or to find the optimal threshold.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of using ML to fine tune code that runs the thing I'm looking for. The only thing that I thought would help was to use logistic regression to plot an optimal threshold for previous data points that the program would save. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ike Imho you should start by determining the similarity measure. Are your real objects similar to the example you give? If yes you could look at [string similarity measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). Determining the optimal threshold can be done just by maximizing the "correct answers", but that requires annotated examples.